# Step form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a step form using javascript and php. The form has three steps. Step1 has two buttons `B1` and `Next`, step2 also has two buttons `B2` and `Next`, finally step3 has two buttons - `B3` and `Submit`. Now I want to add validation to the form using javascript (JQuery), so as to make sure that buttons `B1`, `B2` and `B3` are clicked before clicking `Submit`.

**Important Note:** The page reloads every time you press `Next`, thus after coming to step3 when you check whether button `B1` was clicked in step1 using below code

```
document.getElementById('B1').onclick = function() {
   alert("button B1 was clicked");
}​;
```

it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads will be helpful for you

Comment: Local storage OR you could use an ajax solution, so the form doesn't have to refresh in the browser each time. Either should work fine. Personally I'm bias to AJAX as you could do a nice animation for each time the button is clicked, i.e. a simple `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` animation.

Comment: Thanks to both of u.. I found the answer in session storage as mentioned in the stackoverflow post mentioned by usman

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit tricky for solve your problem but could work...or maybe gives you idea to solve it.

If you go to server after each step, it's not in javascript but in php you need to add validation.

As you like to go to server (php) between each step, you can have every form inputs at once and only display needed step.

You also needs a current-step input to know in php at witch step you are.

> HTML

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="currentStep" value="">      
  <div class="container-step1">
    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <input type="hidden" id="B1Clicked" value="N">
    Step 1 
    <button type="button" id="B1">Button 1</button>
    <button type="submit" class="step-submit" current-step="1">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container-step2">
    <!-- Step 2 -->
    <input type="hidden" id="B2Clicked" value="N">
    Step 1 
    <button type="button" id="B2">Button 2</button>
    <button type="submit" class="step-submit" current-step="2"id="Next">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container-step3">
    <!-- Step 3 -->
    <input type="hidden" id="B3Clicked" value="N">
    Step 1 
    <button type="button" id="B3">Button 3</button>
    <button type="submit" class="step-submit" current-step="3"id="Next">Next</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

> JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Hide all steps
  $("div[class^='container-step']").hide();
  // Show only step container give by server
  $('.container-step<?= $currentStep ?>').show();

  $('#B1').onclick = function() {
     $('#B1Clicked').value('Y');
  }​;
  $('#B2').onclick = function() {
     $('#B2Clicked').value('Y');
  }​;
  $('#B3').onclick = function() {
     $('#B2Clicked').value('Y');
  }​;
  // Set current step
  $('.step-submit').on('click', function(e) {
     var currentStepValue = $(e.target).attr('current-step');
     $('#currentStep').value(currentStepValue);
     return true;
  }​);
});
```

> PHP

```
// Read current step from interface
$currentStep = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'currentStep');
// Test for first show
if (null == $currentStep) $currentStep = 1;

// Fetch all step data
$b1Clicked = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'B1Clicked');
$b2Clicked = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'B2Clicked');
$b3Clicked = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'B3Clicked');

// If all step has been clicked -> do validation
if ($b1Clicked == 'Y' && $b2Clicked == 'Y' && $b3Clicked == 'Y') {

  // Add your validation here

}
```

Comment: thank you for ur wonderful effort.. but this isnt exactly what i was looking for

Comment: No prob, localStorage is easy and good solution. I'm a bit too old fashion :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can you `localStorage` to store button click information. In the following link you can get useful information.

[Fiddle Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zcttep61/27/)